# Given two elements $g,h$ in a finite group $G$ of the same order, does there exist a finite group $G'$ containing $G$ where they are conjugate?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $g,h\in G$ be two elements of the same order. Does there exist a larger finite group $G'\ge G$ such that $g,h$ are conjugate in $G'$?

If not, what is known about groups which have this property?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson why not provide a link to that other question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324939/forced-conjugation-of-elements-in-finite-groups/2324940#2324940

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been answered already in a different topic.

Comment: I've voted to reopen.  Just because this question was answered in the answers to a different question does not mean it is off-topic.

Comment: @AndyPutman duplicate is not considered as "off-topic". The situation here is peculiar since the first question (one special instance of $G$: of order 8 with $g,h$ of order 2) was asked on MathOF and then moved to MathSE (so that the question can't any longer be closed as duplicate) and possibly it wouldn't have been closed if it had been asked in a more general context. I didn't vote (to close nor to reopen).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Two subgroups are isomorphic iff they are conjugate in some larger finite group.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Isomorphic_iff_potentially_conjugate_in_finite)

If you have two subgroups $A,B$ of a finite group $G$ and $\sigma: A\to B$ is an isomorphism. Then there exists a group $G'$ containing $G$ and an element $g'\in G'$ such that $\sigma$ is induced by conjugation by $g'$. For your question this follows by taking $A,B$ to be the cyclic groups generated by your two elements of the same order.

Comment: The OP asked for a finite group.

Comment: @MarkSapir, Yes, this answer only considers finite groups.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I did not notice "finite" in the first line of the answer, and just looked a  the rest of the answer.

Comment: @YCor there is a link to a groupprops page with a proof of this specific fact. I personally like groupprops as an encyclopedic resource since it also allows you to search through related theorems and similar statements.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi sorry, I only saw the statement without proof; there's indeed a proof hidden below

Answer (score 15):

This is a theorem of Bernhard Neumann and his wife (and, as he once told me, can be found in his Collection of Works; he even told me which volume I should look at, but I do not remember; I am sure mathsci can help). A "modern" proof of that fact is easy. Basically suppose that  two finite groups $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.  Then take $F=G\times H$ and the HNN extension $T$ of $F$ with associated subgroups $G, H$. In $T$, the subgroups $G$ and $H$ are conjugate. Now, $T$ is infinite, but as every HNN extension of a finite group, $T$  is residually finite because it is virtually free (say, by Stallings ends theorem). Hence $T$ has a finite quotient $R$ such that the natural maps from $G$ and $H$ into $R$ are embeddings. Thus $G$ and $H$ are conjugated subgroups of a finite group $R$.

**Edit 1:** The paper is this: MR0064042 
Neumann, B. H.; Neumann, Hanna "Partial endomorphisms of finite groups." J. London Math. Soc. 29, (1954). 434–440.

If $G$ and $H$ are given as subgroups in the same finite group $F$, then there is no need to take $F= G\times H$.

**Edit 2:** In fact the paper by Neumanns cited above proves a much stronger result when there is only a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ (the question is then whether it extends to an endomorphism of a bigger finite group). The fact about arbitrary isomorphic finite subgroups is proved first in Neumann, B. H. (notice the absence of Hanna Neumann)
An essay on free products of groups with amalgamations. Philos. Trans. Roy. Soc. London. Ser. A. 246, (1954). 503–554. The paper gives two proofs of this fact (Corollary 18.3). The first uses amalgamated products and is essentially the proof above. The second proof is attributed to Ph. Hall and is essentially the same as Will Sawin's proof discussed in the comments.

Comment: Why not a theorem by Hanna Neumann and her husband?

Comment: @YCor: Maybe, because it corresponds to the alphabetical order ?

Comment: @YCor:  because he is the first named author and because I met him and not Hanna Neumann (who was a much more popular mathematician in the USSR, and looked very much similar to my aunt Fania, by the way).

Comment: @MarkSapir That's quite amazing, since from what I gather Hanna was a German (and an aristocratic one, at that).

Comment: @IgorRivin:  Yes, I  learned it many years after I saw her portrait  in Canberra, and I was really shocked.

Comment: Since the HNN+residual finiteness argument was given by HJRW in a comment to Will's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2324940/35400, I have added a cw answer to that post to rewrite this short argument there https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2340373/35400

Comment: The Neumanns' theorem addresses the question for arbitrary subgroups. But for cyclic subgroups, as in the question, Will Sawin's construction (linked to in comments by Francois Ziegler) relies only on nineteenth century mathematics. I bet the answer to this question was known 50 years before the Neumanns' paper.

Comment: @HJRW: If it was so, I would like to see a reference. How much would want to bet?

Comment: @MarkSapir, unfortunately, my assertion is unfalsifiable, and therefore you shouldn't bet on it, since you'll never win your money. :) But I would bet a large sum of money that, if you had asked the question of Sylow, say, he could have told you the answer pretty quickly.

Comment: @HJRW: I think I know all results about finite groups obtained before 1954. This one is new to me and apparently Neumanns did not know about it too, otherwise they would refer to it in their papers. So the statement "the answer ... was known 50 years before Neumanns paper" is very likely to be wrong. It can be easily checked by looking at each paper on finite groups that appeared before 1904. The reason is simple: nobody asked the question because there was no motivation for it. The question answered by Neumanns first appeared in their earlier paper.

Comment: I still bet that, had you asked him the question, Sylow (or even Cayley) could have answered it pretty quickly.  But if your knowledge is as encyclopaedic as you claim, then obviously I have to defer.

Comment: @HJRW Nothing specific to cyclic subgroups; Will's argument works for an arbitrary pair of finite subgroups in a finite group (since both act freely on the left on $F$). If necessary I've added this to my cw answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2340373/35400

Comment: @YCor: That is the proof of Ph Hall, see Edit 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was reopened in spite of a duplicate in MathSE, I also "duplicate" my answer from there (a little improved anyway), so as to provide a self-contained answer. I leave it cw since it relies on ideas form other answers and comments.

(a) The answer to the OP's question is yes, and more generally one has:

> *Fact.* Consider a finite group $F$ and two subgroups $A,B$ with an isomorphism $t:A\to B$. Then one can embed $F$ in a larger finite group in which $A$ and $B$ are conjugate (the conjugation inducing the isomorphism $t$ from $A$ to $B$).

This applies in particular to the case when $A,B$ are cyclic subgroups of the same order.

*Proof of the fact.* $A$ has two free actions on $F$, one being given by $a\cdot g=ag$, the other by $a\cdot g=t(a)g$. Writing $k=|F/A|$, find $k$ points $x_1,\dots,x_k$, one in each orbit of the first action, and $k$ points $y_1,\dots,y_k$, one in each orbit of the second action. Then extend the assignment $x_i\mapsto y_i$ to a permutation $\sigma$ of $F$, by the assignment $\sigma(ax_i)=t(a)y_i$. This is well-defined by freeness of the action. Then $$\sigma(abx_i)=t(ab)y_i=t(a)t(b)y_i=t(a)\sigma(bx_i)$$ for all $a,b\in A$ and $i$, and thus $\sigma(ag)=t(a)\sigma(g)$ for all $a\in A$ and $g\in F$. In other words, $\sigma\circ L_a=L_{t(a)}\circ \sigma$. So in the permutation group of $F$, where $F$ is identified to its image through left multiplication, the isomorphism $t:A\to B$ is realized by conjugation by $\sigma$. $\Box$

This is essentially [Will's argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324939/forced-conjugation-of-elements-in-finite-groups/2324940#2324940), which was only written for $A,B$ cyclic.

(b) In the same setting, the universal group in which $A$ and $B$ are conjugate through $t$, is the HNN extension $H$ of $(F,A,B,t)$, defined by the relative presentation
$$\langle u,G\mid uau^{-1}=t(a),\forall a\in A\rangle.$$

It is well-known that this HNN-extension is virtually free and hence residually finite. Thus, there exists a finite quotient of $H$ in which $F$ is mapped injectively, and in this quotient $A$ and $B$ are indeed conjugate (by $t$).

Of course this argument (mentioned by HJRW in the comments to Will's answer), which looks somewhat immediate at first glance, is less elementary than the one in (a) since it relies on residual finiteness of HNN extensions of finite groups; anyway it's a very natural proof since the construction is universal.